# Day and night world map

Tags: software-recommendation, clock

Is there a day and night world map + clock available in the Ubuntu repositories?

It should show the regions of the earth covered by sunlight. For example:

[image: Geochron]

<sub>Image author: Clonodin. Image license: [CC BY-SA 4.0 International](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en). Image source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Geochron_20180207_at_office.jpg</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is an app called `sunclock` to show the local time around the world and the areas of the globe which are in night or day.

You can install it by using

```
sudo apt install sunclock
```

[image: screenshot of sunclock]

Comment: Thank you. Looks like development has stopped. The upstream, https://github.com/mdoege/Sunclock, is gone.

Comment: It seems that development has resumed here: https://github.com/nongiach/Sunclock